# Datatable Footer Callback

Tags: laravel-backpack

Is there any feature for this footer callback?

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

I would like to sum up a column for each page or filter the data.

As I read the `src/resources/views/crud/inc/datatables_logic.blade.php` seem like does not have the footer keyword.

Not sure this version support for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish the blade file using `php artisan backpack:publish crud/inc/datatables_logic`. Then you'll find it in your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/inc/` and be able to change it to fit your needs - like adding your own footer callback logic.

This is perfectly fine to do when you need a feature that Backpack doesn't support out-of-the-box (it can't possibly support *everything*) - but make sure you don't overdo it and publish *a lot* of blade files. When you're publishing a blade file:

- you're basically forfeiting the *minor* updates for that file;
- when a new *major* Backpack version comes around, if it has breaking changes in that particular file, the fact that you have it published and customised will make it a little more difficult to upgrade - you'll need to look at the `diff` between the files and manually make the same breaking changes;

Comment: thanks for your answer, so I have an idea what to do for the right track. Thanks!